# Is this a good case for using pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, summarization

I am doing a database call against MSSQL in Python (and I'm on Linux).
After finally getting all of the deps done to do this, my calls typically run about 1,000,000 records per pull. (The database details a problem, the city encountered and the solution)

The record set looks like this..... (I'm only including the relevant columns)

```
Description, City, Solution
Won't Start, Denver, Replace Spark Plugs
Won't Start, Chicago, Add Gas
Light Out, Denver, Replace Bulb
Flat Tire, New York, Change Tire
...
...
```

What I'm needing to do is do a count on the unique descriptions, and under each description a count of the unique cities and below the cities a unique count of the solution.

I'm a relative newb to Python (but I love it the more I implement it) and in the past using another language, I would have probably exported the entire record set to SQLite and then summarized using standard SQL.

This just seems to be a solution itching for a pandas solutions, but my lack of knowledge on the best tool for this sort of operation is somewhat lacking since I'm still learning Python.

Are there any pandas people out there that can chime in on this topic and maybe even point me in the right direction? 
- JW

Comment: Why not just use a database query to get the info you want?

Comment: @7stud, I'm querying using T-SQL against MSSQL which is horrifically slow as it is and adding WHERE only grinds it to timeout. Just pulling the whole dataset is quicker.

Comment: What about: `COUNT ( { [ [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression ] | * } ) 
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )`--> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: ... and this will allow me to pull it off in one statement? Otherwise a python solution is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a code sample without knowing what your data (type, etc.) looks like. But I think you're better served using [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this since you need only a count of unique data. Your count is just the set length.

And a set will be faster than pandas for this.